# A 'hardeasy' geometry problem from Bangladesh mathematical olympiad

Tags: logic, circles

Three concentric circles ω1, ω2, ω3 with radius r1, r2, r3 such that r1 + r3 ≥ 2r2,construct a line that intersects ω1, ω2, ω3 at A, B, C respectively such that AB = BC.

I got the problem partially solved. Here may be two cases.

Case 1: when $r_1+r_3=2r_2$, this is easy to prove that all lines in the region $[\omega_3]-[\omega_1]$ touching the circumference of the three circles (not tangent to $\omega_1$) can be considered as our solution because in that case we have to have $r_3-r_2=r_2-r_1$ which is from $r_1+r_3=2r_2$ and we'll be done.

Case 2: when $r_1+r_3>2r_2$, The answer, I know, will be the lines again in the $[\omega_3]-[\omega_1]$ region and touching the circumferences of the three circles but will be tangent to $\omega_1$. I can not prove this yet. But I have tried many approaches. In case 2, it is known that the value of $BC$ is $\sqrt{r_2^2-r_1^2}$. And what is left is to prove that $AB$ equals that.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the following drawing. Since $AB=BC$, we have

$$
OA^{2}+OC^{2}=AB^{2}+BC^{2}+2OB^{2}
$$

Substituting $OA=r_{1}$, $OB=r_{2}$, and $OC=r_{3}$ yields the following:

$$
AB=BC=\sqrt{\frac{r_{1}^{2}+r_{3}^{2}-2r_{2}^{2}}{2}}
$$

The expression inside the square root is non-negative, since by using QM-AM inequality and $r_{1}+r_{3}\geq 2r_{2}$, we have

$$
\frac{r_{1}^{2}+r_{3}^{2}-2r_{2}^{2}}{2}\geq\left(\frac{r_{1}+r_{3}}{2}\right)^{2}-r_{2}^{2}\geq0
$$

[image: Construction]

Therefore, a method to construct the line is: choose an arbitrary point $B$ on $\omega_{2}$. Then draw a circle with radius $\sqrt{\frac{r_{1}^{2}+r_{3}^{2}-2r_{2}^{2}}{2}}$. $A$ and $C$ are the intersection between this new circle with $\omega_{1}$ and $\omega_{3}$, respectively.

Notice that $\frac{r_{1}^{2}+r_{3}^{2}-2r_{2}^{2}}{2}=0$ if and only if $r_{1}=r_{2}=r_{3}$, so all three circles coincide. In this case, any line intersecting the three circles will do.

**Additional Explanation**

The cosine rule states that

$$
\begin{aligned}
OA^{2}&=OB^{2}+AB^{2}-2OB\cdot AB\cos{\left(\angle OBA\right)}\\
OC^{2}&=OB^{2}+BC^{2}-2OB\cdot BC\cos{\left(\angle OBC\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Because $AB=BC$ and $\angle OBA + \angle OBC = \pi$, we can sum the two equations and obtain

$$
OA^{2}+OC^{2}=AB^{2}+BC^{2}+2OB^{2}
$$

Comment: The 'construction' link can't be opened, however, I don't understand your reasoning, the three circles are given, and the term 'since $AB=BC$' seems to be an assumption, but that's what to be drawn.

Comment: @SoniaSultana I didn’t put any link. The construction part is just a plain text. Just follow the construction part and you will get your line

Comment: As a high school student, I may not be capable of understanding this, thank you!

Comment: Oh, but there is a link.

Comment: @SoniaSultana ah that’s usually link to the original picture. If you are interested, the first half of my answer comes from the “cosine rule” of triangle

Comment: Oh I got it, but can you please elaborate how you used cosine rule here?

Comment: @SoniaSultana I added the explanation on that to the answer